# How to do a task depending on Stripe API error response

Tags: php, stripe-payments

Currently using Stripe to process payments however I would like to perform an SQL statement which will ban a user lets say when the Stripe risk evaluation is `highest`.

My current charge code using stripe's PHP library contains a basic error exception message:

```
 <?php
require 'lib/Stripe.php';

if ($_POST) {
  Stripe::setApiKey($stripeSecretKey);
  $error = '';
  $success = '';

  try {
    if (empty($_POST['street']) || empty($_POST['city']) || empty($_POST['zip']))
      throw new Exception("Fill out all required fields.");
    if (!isset($_POST['stripeToken']))
      throw new Exception("The Stripe Token was not generated correctly");
    Stripe_Charge::create(array("amount" => $price * 100,
                                "currency" => "gbp",
                                "card" => $_POST['stripeToken'],
                                "description" => "User: " . $userUsername . " - " . $userEmail,
                                "receipt_email" => $userEmail));

    $success = '<div class="alert alert-success">
                <strong>Success!</strong> Your payment was successful, Redirecting...
                </div>';
                header('Refresh: 3; URL=https://urlhere');


  }
  catch (Exception $e) {
    $error = '<div class="alert alert-danger">
              <strong>Error!</strong> '.$e->getMessage().'
              </div>';
  }
}

if(!(empty($success)))

                $txid = generateTxid();
{
                $SQL = $odb -> prepare("INSERT INTO `payments` VALUES(NULL, :price, :planid, :userid, :payer, :transactionid, UNIX_TIMESTAMP())");
                $SQL -> execute(array(':price' => $price, ':planid' => $planID, ':userid' => $userID, ':payer' => $userEmail, ':transactionid' => $txid));


                $unit = $plan['unit'];
                $length = $plan['length'];
                $newExpire = strtotime("+{$length} {$unit}");
                $updateSQL = $odb -> prepare("UPDATE `users` SET `expire` = :expire, `membership` = :plan WHERE `ID` = :id");
                $updateSQL -> execute(array(':expire' => $newExpire, ':plan' => (int)$planID, ':id' => (int)$userID));
}
?>
```

With reference to https://stripe.com/docs/api#charge_object I can see that under the PHP tab it has the `outcome` object which could be used in my cas ehowever not sure how to implement it.

Comment: Don't edit questions to invalidate existing answers, instead ask a new question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the response from your charge creation. Look at the risk_level attribute and write a condition that does something when the condition is met.

```
$response = Stripe_Charge::create(...
```

To get the risk_level attribute:

```
print $response->outcome->risk_level
```

P.S. you should be checking the charge response to verify it succeeded and not just assuming it succeeded if an Exception was not thrown. It could be Pending, which is not an Exception but it's also not a success, for example.

Comment: if there's any more issues, raise another flag.